# get the latest value for column

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to get the latest or last input of the value of an item(same item I input) in MYSQL?

Example:

I have a 2 fields, fldName and fldDuration.

I input the name for fldName is : LAPTOP

then for fldDuration is : 10 seconds

So then, if the total duration is only 5 minutes. Then the present total duration now is 4:50 minutes. BUT what if I enter again the same name yet different duration.

Example 2:

fldName : LAPTOP

fldDuration : 5 seconds

Problem:  Is there a way to get the latest total duration of a LAPTOP so that I can compute the total duration and the duration when saving it to my database.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don`t get it neither.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question ? I don't understand what you want to do ? What's your input ? What's the exact output expected ? What does your database looks like ? etc.

Comment: @Kolink...sorry I already edit my post...I forgot to paste the problem

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, wou want to select the "latest" entry, that you have created?

If so, add a column (id, Auto Increment) and reverse sort your query using that id. Limit the result from 0 to 1 and you got it.

Comment: yeah thanks for understanading... I already search for getting the last ID.. using this "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" but is there a way also to get the last fldid at the same time the fldname of a row?

Comment: @dognose Ever heard of concurrency? Never ever do it like you do now. Use LAST_INSERT_ID()!

Comment: @tombom if you reuse the id to create related datasets, you are right, ofc. But as far as i understood the tc, its just about listing the result. And there is no concurrency.